# Ubuntu 14.04 "No Bluetooth adapters found" with 0cf3:3004 USB device

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I have a Lenovo B50 with Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS without physical switch. I turned off the bluetooth using the bluetooth indicator. After that, the bluetooth indicator never more appeared and I can't switch it on using "Systems settings" (grey letters displaying "No Bluetooth adapters found").

```
~$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[   22.017841] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   22.017861] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   22.017870] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   22.017873] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   22.017878] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   22.211081] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   22.211084] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   22.211092] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  100.024281] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[  100.024293] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[  100.024298] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
09:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

As you can see, my BT isn't in the lsusb results.

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:0652 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My /etc/rc.local file is:

```
modprobe -v ath3k
modprobe -v btusb
echo 0cf3 3004 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ath3k/new_id
echo 0cf3 3004 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id 
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/24 -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
modprobe ath3k
exit 0
```

Comment: Did BT work before? If it did, then my solution will not work for you.

Comment: I don't see an Atheros Bluetooth device in the `lsusb` results just a Microsoft Nano transceiver for bluetooth

Comment: @Pilot6 effectively my BT worked fine before.

Comment: Well, then you have the AR3012 one. I am deleting my answer.

Comment: I suggest reporting this issue to Launchpad or search for an existing bug.

Comment: But it used to be there, did not it? Try to remove the Microsoft one.

Comment: The problem was solved unistalling and reinstalling blueman. How can I mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved unistalling and reinstalling blueman